# How to run selenium on RHEL sever through SSH?

Tags: selenium, ssh, selenium-webdriver, rhel5

I have developed a fully working Selenium suite using Java webdriver and firefox and is working perfectly fine. Now our requirement is to run the same test suite in Red Hat server (RHEL ) so that it should run as cron job everyday. The only way we access our server is through Putty ( SSH ). Anyone can guide me how to run my selenium test suite on RHEL sever ? I need a way to kick automation suite through SSH or HTTP request.

Any suggestions??

Thanks

Thanks,
Faiz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this using :

Install firefox on Linux
Install xorg-x11-xauth

Before executing the automation script just call - "export DISPLAY=:0.0"

This will cause display to be redirected to mail display. Execution will start on Firefox (one could see execution if display is connected ) and will output results back to SSH